# PHP : upload a file in specific directory and not to directory as per configuration (tmp_upload_dir param) in php.ini config file

Tags: php

We are facing a difficulty in uploading a file functionality developed in PHP on a Linux box. The file always gets uploaded in /tmp directory which is configured as the value of tmp_upload_dir parameter in php.ini file. We tried to upload the file to a different directory but it erred out. Is there a way where we can overwrite the default value of tmp_upload_dir dynamically (via program/code) or upload a file other to other directory than what is configured in php.ini file?

Comment: Your script should use `move_uploaded_file()` to put the file where you want it.

Comment: Thanks but is it not possible to directly place it in some other folder

Comment: How is PHP supposed to know where to upload it to? The client can't specify this.

Comment: You can change this via `.htaccess` or `.user.ini`. But PHP will create a *temporary* file anyway, and delete it afterwards if not moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', 'your_directory_goes_here');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: This is how the directory value is written programmatically. What exactly is the issue? Just saying didn't work doesn't help.

Comment: It seems that some PHP configurations cannot be changed. When we set the new value we found that the parameter retains the old value

Comment: You have to do this _before_ the user submits the upload, not in the script that processes the upload form.

Comment: Well, yes. This has to be set in some globally accessed/included file.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you move the file after is uploaded? check this [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) and the examples